# Is there any way to send approval to higher authority in Azure Devops Build Pipeline in classic editor

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I'm trying to send approval to higher authority before build(CI) get started in Azure DevOps. We are using Team Foundation version control and classic build editor pipeline in which we need to configure approvals for a specific build pipeline. Do we have any chance to send approval before build get started ?

In my research I didn't find exact output for sending approval before build get started in TFS. Please share your valuable inputs.

Answer (score -1):

Normally the stages carried out in the construction must be autonomous and without impact on your infrastructure. For example, compile code or perform automated tests (example sonarque junit etc.)
I don't know your use of the build phase but I advise you to leave the build phase without approvers and send your code in an artifact. In a second step you can set up a release with an approvers on the environment.

There is no approval option but the possibility of adding an agentless task to have a manual validation to the people notified.
It is not "obligatory" to go through people to warn but at least it warns before deployment.

Comment: Yes, we can follow the approval process in release which we are aware of the process. Just wanted to know If there is any chance of approval in build phase ?